# Once I read a excel file with apache POI how do I print the sheet in a txt file?

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

First I would like to thank all for your time in reading my post!

I use netbeans IDE 8.0.1 and I´m new in JAVA.

I have been searching in google many ways to read & write excel files using Apache POI. There are a lot of tutorials and information about it, but I still can´t write the excel file (or sheet) that I read in a .txt file.

I have this code that is really good because declare a workbooks if is a xls or a xlsx file. But it dosen't print what is read as a table in netbeans, so I think that I will have the same problem if I try to print it as a .txt file.

Can someone help me please? Thanks and sorry for the code paste is my first post!

Here is the code:

```
package read_write_excel_V2;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class JIA_ReadingRewritingWorbooks_v2 { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    String fname = "ExcelJAVAWrite_demo.xlsx"; 
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(fname); 
    String fileExtn = GetFileExtension(fname); 
    Workbook wb_xssf;       // Declare XSSF WorkBook 
    Workbook wb_hssf;       // Declare HSSF WorkBook 
    Sheet sheet = null;     

    if (fileExtn.equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx")) { 
        wb_xssf = new XSSFWorkbook(inp); 
        log("xlsx="+wb_xssf.getSheetName(0)); 
        sheet = wb_xssf.getSheetAt(0); 
    } 

    if (fileExtn.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) { 
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(inp); 
        wb_hssf = new HSSFWorkbook(fs); 
        log("xls="+wb_hssf.getSheetName(0)); 
        sheet = wb_hssf.getSheetAt(0); 
    } 

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = (Row) rows.next();  

        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator(); 

        while (cells.hasNext()){ 
            Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next(); 

        switch ( cell.getCellType() ) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
            log(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()); 
            break; 
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: 

                if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) { 
                    log(cell.getDateCellValue()+""); 
                } else { 
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 
                } 
                break; 
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: 
                log(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+""); 
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                log(cell.getCellFormula()); 
                break; 
            default: 
        } 
        } 
    } 
    inp.close(); 
    } 

private static void log(String message) { 
    System.out.println(message); 
 } 

private static String GetFileExtension(String fname2) { 
    String fileName = fname2; 
    String fname=""; 
    String ext=""; 
    int mid= fileName.lastIndexOf("."); 
    fname=fileName.substring(0,mid); 
    ext=fileName.substring(mid+1,fileName.length()); 
    return ext; 
}
 }
```

I add what @dkatzel recommends but the printing is still in rows. The code:

```
public class JIA_ReadingRewritingWorbooks_v2_Tmp { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    ....

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 

    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = (Row) rows.next(); 

        int numCells =row.getLastCellNum();
        for(int i=0; i<numCells; i++){
        Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
            // If not defined, cell could be null
            // Do your cell printing here
            //Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next(); 

        switch ( cell.getCellType() ) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: 
            log(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString()); 
            break; 
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: 

                if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) { 
                    log(cell.getDateCellValue()+""); 
                } else { 
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()); 
                } 
                break; 
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: 
                log(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+""); 
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
                log(cell.getCellFormula()); 
                break; 
            default: 
        } 
        //}
        }

    } 
    inp.close(); 
} 

private static void log(String message) { 
    System.out.println(message); 
 } 

private static String GetFileExtension(String fname2) { 
    String fileName = fname2; 
    String fname=""; 
    String ext=""; 
    int mid= fileName.lastIndexOf("."); 
    fname=fileName.substring(0,mid); 
    ext=fileName.substring(mid+1,fileName.length()); 
    return ext; 
}
}
```

I have this results:
This type of results I´m getting:
[https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10527311_10153011702894311_4509818841257258400_n.jpg?oh=d724cbfc9a96aa29a07f0d26a7c81726&oe=54B5C2A5&**gda**=1421766835_79c0648ddbeb2eb966027cd62f8d241a](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/10527311_10153011702894311_4509818841257258400_n.jpg?oh=d724cbfc9a96aa29a07f0d26a7c81726&oe=54B5C2A5&__gda__=1421766835_79c0648ddbeb2eb966027cd62f8d241a)

I wish to have this type of results, tabulated:
[https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10710855_10153011703104311_5065636883843539807_n.jpg?oh=9bc931559b3e2380068b7a7ecac35b57&oe=54ABCEC3&**gda**=1421306774_8cf6356575f6c255c52f316ed9d1fba0](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10710855_10153011703104311_5065636883843539807_n.jpg?oh=9bc931559b3e2380068b7a7ecac35b57&oe=54ABCEC3&__gda__=1421306774_8cf6356575f6c255c52f316ed9d1fba0)

or print the results in .txt file. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any exceptions thrown? Does it print ANYTHING?

Comment: Yes, its read every row and prints by row, not the matrix.
run:
xlsx=Family Data
ID
NAME
LASTNAME
AGE
1.0
Ingacio
Alarcon
59
2.0
Esperanza
Marambio
50
3.0
Juan Ignacio
Alarcon
27
4.0
Katherine
Marsh
25
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you use the cell iterator, which the [Javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#cellIterator%28%29) says

> Cell iterator over the physically defined cells

Which I take to mean it will skip blank cells.

If you want to include blanks you will need to iterate over them manually:

instead of

```
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator(); 
while (cells.hasNext()){ 
        Cell cell = (Cell) cells.next(); 
       ...
}
```

Do this:

```
int numCells =row.getLastCellNum();
for(int i=0; i<numCells; i++){
    Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
    //if not defined, cell could be null
    //do your cell printing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dkatzel, but I don't understand where I have to attach that code.

Comment: Thanks, but still printing rows and not in a matrix. Also do you know how can I export the reading to a txt file in the same code?

Answer (score 0):

```
String actualOutputWBString = new XSSFExcelExtractor(actualWorkbook).getText();
```